# How to disable Logcat in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Im facing with a very strange issue and i dont know yet the source of it but the thing is: Every time i click on the Logcat interface in Eclipse, it will crash in 5 seconds and goes to state "Not responding", its really annoying, i just want to get rid of it.

Please anyone can tell me how to disable Logcat interface in Eclipse ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turn it off in Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Logcat -> Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace.

Comment: Holy cow - I don't know why this *is* enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers are good. I find that eclipse still seems to be recieveing logcat in the background... this is still an issue for all you that find eclipse hangs or freezes or CPU 100% when you plug in a phone or start the emulator.

The only reliable way if have found to stop eclipse from freezing is to click the pause button on right of the logcat window **before** plugging in or starting anything. then i just minimize it.

To me, the problem is that eclipse uses a lot of resources to parse the logcat. 
Correct me on this point, but on my duel-core, eclipse only seems to use one processor at a time. This runs up to 100% when logcat is on. This hangs eclipse specifically as long as the phone is plugged in (my PC does not hang since the other processor is still available). There are a lot of apps on my phone, and there tends to be a lot of logging going on.

Anyway, the pause button works really well for me. Maybe it is a new feature, i don't know when it was introduced. You can still use logcat from the console.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are using old one Logcat(with android as it's symbol) that is deprecated, update to the new one... i think then this problem will be solved.

Even if you are using the new one but still there is problem go for complete new plugin for Android development.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably related to Eclipse ADT [Issue 34945](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34945). They still did not fix this problem, and only solution is to avoid showing LogCat in any Eclipse Perspective. Easiest way to do this is to disconnect all your mobile devices/emulators, start eclipse and go to Debug/DDMS perspective and close LogCat view.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I hade this issue and could continue my work by closing logcat!

Answer (score 1):

I'm  facing same problem. When plug in any of my phones, eclipse freezes for few minutes while fetching logs from device. I have latest stable Eclipse (3.7.2), and latest ADT plugin (18.0.0.v201203301601-306762) with up-to-date SDK.

My way to avoid such thing is to clear all logs from device before i start Eclipse. Commands are:

1. list your device(es) with `adb devices`
2. `adb -s SERIAL_NUMBER_OF_DEVICE logcat -c`